# Sorting a 2D list alphabetically?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a 2D list such as this:

```
lst = [['c', 'd', 'b'], ['d', 'c', 'a'], ['b', 'a', 'c']]
```

I would first like to sort each list within the list alphabetically like this:

```
lst = [['b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

And finally, I would like to sort the whole list alphabetically which takes into account each element in a sublist:

```
lst = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'c', 'd']]
```

What would be the fastest way to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fastest way in general should be just as you described it:

```
for sublist in lst:
    sublist.sort()

lst.sort()
```

Alternatively, if you want to do it out of place:

```
new_lst = [sorted(sublist) for sublist in lst]
new_lst.sort()
```

Comment: Also `new_lst = sorted(map(sorted, lst))`. But it seems the list comprehension is faster on my PC